# SSD not detected during Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10

Existing OS is Windows 10 installed on SSD.
When I tried to install Ubuntu, the only partition available is HDD. I don't see SSD at all. So, I have no choice but to install Ubuntu on HDD.

**nvme0n1 = Windows 10, sda = Ubuntu**

The following `lsblk` and `df -h` taken after installation of both OS. I'll reproduce the issue in VM and will share the screenshot later.

**lsblk**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0 187.1G  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0   513M  0 part 
└─sda4        8:4    0 743.9G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 476.3G  0 part 
user@ubuntu:~$
```

**df -h**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda4       732G  7.8G  687G   2% /
tmpfs           7.8G   40M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2   95M   31M   65M  33% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           1.6G   32K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2       188G  3.2G  184G   2% /media/user/New Volume
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Would it be possible to install both OS in SSD, and not HDD?

Comment: Make sure [Windows is not hibernated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation).

Comment: I guess Windows is installed on nvme0n1p4. There is no room on this disk to install ubuntu on. You need to shrink the windows partition.

Comment: Many systems need UEFI update and SSD firmware update.

Comment: @Carl, how do you know windows is installed on nvme0n1p4? Btw, Partition Magic can be used to shrink windows partition right? No wonder I don't see it at all during installation ... It's been fully utilized by windows

Comment: @Carl Ubuntu installer can shrink the Windows partition normally…

Comment: @Melebius. Windows has been shut down properly. I've just moved Windows to HDD partition and then boot with Ubuntu USB again trying to install it. Guess what, I still can't see SSD as an option.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Status please...

Comment: @Sabrina did you find the disk set to RAID in your BIOS? Is the disk ENABLED in your BIOS? Does gparted see the disk?

Comment: @Sabrina status please

Answer (score 6):

You've got a single SSD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem. Some users found Choice #2 to be easier.

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
   -  Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
   - Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
   - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
   - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: @Melebius learning is always a good thing :-) Whenever I see that a Ubuntu installer won't see the user's primary target disk, it's almost always that the disk is set as RAID in the BIOS. Now, there could be other things... like the SSD being used as a primary cache for the HDD... or SSD firmware needs an update... or the BIOS needs an update... a partitioning problem... or maybe even a hibernation problem... but RAID is usually the problem, and it only takes a second to check the BIOS setting.

Comment: Raid mode was the problem for me. However, I found a simpler, less frightening method of switching to AHCI: enable booting to safe mode using msconfig, then shutdown. Change the settings in BIOS to use AHCI. Then boot Windows (to safe mode). Run msconfig again and disable booting to safe mode. Reboot to normal Windows.

Comment: @heynnema hi, could you please explain how to revert into RAID mode? Used BIOS to change back to Intel Accelerated RAID but when restart Windows crashes

Comment: @1w3j Doesn't it work when set to AHCI? Which procedure did you use? Can you set the BIOS back to RST/RAID? You may have to use your Windows Install/Repair disk to fix this.

Comment: @heynnema I used the 2nd one. I did set back the BIOS to RAID and produced crashing on windows startup. What I wan't to do is restart the default configuration as posted by the OP. Have a 2020 laptop, I am now checking my BIOS, factory default 1TB SSD configured using Intel RST Premium WIth Intel Optane System Acceleration, But now my new Windows installation was made on AHCI, doesn't matter if I lose data,  I need to revert back to Intel RST. Kindly, I think we need to revert that `bcdedit /deletevalue` command, I'll be attentive to your answer

Comment: just to clarify, I confused RAID to RST, The correct mode was RST, not RAID.

Comment: @1w3j Oh, Optane probably adds another layer of complexity. Did you set the BIOS back to RST? Can you now boot to Windows, even if it's in safe mode? Do you have a Windows Install/Repair disc?

Comment: @heynnema I did set it back to RST, When booting into windows it takes a long wait that finishes in Windows crashed blue screen. I have a a usb stick with a Windows copy in it. Could you please tell how to 'revert' the `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot` command?

Comment: @1w3j I'm sorry... I'm not a Windows or Optane expert... I only know that your problem can probably only be fixed with the Windows Install/Repair disc. However, you might try booting Windows while holding down the SHIFT key and see if that brings you up to a repair screen.

Comment: @1w3j There are a number of helpful videos on YouTube, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RrYhOY-bLA

Comment: @heynnema sorry, my location doesn't allow youtube. I don't understand what does `set safeboot minimal` has to do with the AHCI mode to be set on?

Comment: After using Step 2 in your answer I installed win10, so my current setup was installed on AHCI mode, do I have to delete all the installation and re-install win10 on RST? I want to use RST as there is no need for AHCI anymore

Comment: @1w3j You'll need AHCI if you intend to install Ubuntu. If not, then I would reinstall Windows using RST, but I would use the original restore disc, to make sure the Optane gets properly set up for use with Windows. Sorry you had all of this trouble.